# jQuery Adding data to last column in the table using dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table like this and selection.

```
<select id="choose">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select> 
<table id="num-table">
<thead>
  <th>num 1</th>
  <th>num 2</th>
  <th>num 3</th>
  <th>num 4</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
     <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
     <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
     <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And jquery code !.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#num-table td:last-child').after('<td>4</td>')
  $('#choose').on('change',function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
      $('#num-table tbody tr td:last').after(selected);
  })
})
```

I want to add selected values  to last column(i.e num 4)in jQuery. However the value is added to last row in the last column but not on every row  still it is blank. Any Explaination.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m75L1qpu/13/)

Comment: Well you jquery code is fine, but you haven't included jquery in the jsfiddle. See here I've added jquery https://jsfiddle.net/pyo8bfvt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working Demo**

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var all = new Array();
            $('#choose').on('change', function () {
                var selected = $(this).val();
                var tr = document.querySelectorAll("#num-table tbody > tr");
                valueSet = false;
                $("#num-table tbody > tr").each(function (e) {
                    var tdLen = $(this).children().length;
                    if (tdLen < 4 && !valueSet) {
                        $(this).append(`<td>${selected}</td>`);
                        valueSet = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            });
        })
```